# Marketo rest API: how to get all opportunities using marketo API?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api2, marketo

I am integrating marketo API with my .net website I want to retrieve all opportunities object from marketo by calling REST API. if anyone has an idea please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Just go through the below link

`http://developers.marketo.com/documentation/opportunity-api/get-opportunities/`

Comment: This endpoint requires filters though. The question says "all".